# Term for the outer skin of an airplane

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a seven-letter word beginning with NA that means the outer covering of an airplane or engine.

Comment: Doing a crossword?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not really about the _English Language_. It's a question about terminology specific to a certain field, almost definitely a crossword clue.

Answer (score 3):

[Nacelle](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/nacelle)

> a streamlined enclosure on an aircraft, not part of the fuselage, to accommodate an engine, passengers, crew, etc

It's an unusual word

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nacelle) says

> Like many aviation terms, the word comes from French, in this case from a word for a small boat

See [this question at Aviation SE](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/22603/what-is-the-difference-between-a-nacelle-and-a-cowling#:%7E:text=The%20nacelle%20is%20a%20housing,some%20of%20the%20engine%20nacelles.&text=A%20cowl%20or%20cowling%20is,(for%20inspection%20etc.).) for more details.

[image: Picture courtesy of ST Engineering/https://www.blueskynews.aero/issue-479/ST-Engineering-to-acquire-nacelle-manufacturer-MRA-Systems.html]